# How to move wp-content (or uploads) outside of the Wordpress directory

Tags: customization, uploads, content

I am trying to move the wp-content directory outside of the wordpress directory and hitting all kinds of weird problems. Even though http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder says you can do this, it seems that the directory structure is deeply wired into the WP code. For example, I get error messages like:

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/srv/wp.content/themes) is not within the allowed path(s): (/srv/wordpress/:/tmp) 
in /srv/wordpress/wp-includes/theme.php on line 369
```

All I need to do is to move the uploads directory outside of the main hierarchy. I tried to symlink it as well but then I am getting permission errors.

Did anybody manage to successfully have the wp-content directory, or at least, uploads directory outside of the root directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL`:

```
const WP_CONTENT_DIR = '/path/to/new/directory';
const WP_CONTENT_URL = 'http://content.wp';
```

The new path must be accessible for read and write operation from the WordPress core directory. You might need a helper function to add the new directory path to the `open_basedir` list:

```
/**
 * Add a new directory to the 'open_basedir' list.
 *
 * @link   http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir
 * @param  string $new_dir
 * @return void
 */
function extend_base_dir( $new_dir )
{
    $separator = ':'; // all systems, except Win

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/5879078/299509
    if ( 'WIN' === strtoupper( substr( PHP_OS, 0, 3 ) ) )
        $separator = ';';

    $dirs = explode( $separator, ini_get( 'open_basedir' ) );

    $found = array_search( $new_dir, $dirs );

    // Already accessible
    if ( FALSE !== $found )
        return;

    $dirs[] = $new_dir;

    ini_set( 'open_basedir', join( $separator, $dirs ) );
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
extend_base_dir( WP_CONTENT_DIR );
```

Comment: Thanks @toscho. I actually found open_basedir in my php-fpm configuration and fixed it there. Wonder why Wordpress doesn't document this in the official documentation I linked...

Comment: I am trying to get to a similar way for uploads directory. Any help?

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim Yes. Ask a new question.

Comment: @toscho http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218237/make-wordpress-upload-directory-outside-wordpress-root-with-custom-url

Answer (score 2):

Came here to find out how to move uploads outside the WordPress root. In the end I kept it as simple as creating a symlink and it works just fine.

```
$ pwd
/var/www/wordpress
$ cd ..
$ mkdir uploads
$ chmod 755 uploads
$ ln -sf /var/www/uploads /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
```

Source: [Upload folder of Wordpress outside the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38151851/2199525)

---

For an existing project:

```
$ pwd
/var/www/wordpress
$ mv /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads /var/www/uploads
$ chmod -R 755 /var/www/uploads
$ ln -sf /var/www/uploads /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
```