# Make Wordpress upload directory outside wordpress root with custom url

Tags: php, wp-config, uploads

I want to change the upload directory for Wordpress from `project.dev/wp-content/uploads` to `cdn.project.dev`

Where subdomain **cdn** has DocumentRoot:
`HostPath/project.dev/cdn` while Wordpress is located at `HostPath/project.dev/public_html`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can ask how to change the URLs WordPress generates, and the folder that WordPress stores uploads, however the server component will require nginx or apache knowledge which is off topic on this site

Comment: I would also note that this sounds like a micro-optimisation, you would get more out of using a free CDN such as Photon or another alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can create a very simple plug-in to meet your needs. Here is one based on the now-defunct `directory-control` plugin, previously available at https://github.com/johnbillion/directory-control.

1. In your plugins directory, create a directory called `custom_upload_dir`
2. In that directory, create the following file called `custom_upload_dir.php`

```
    <?php
    /*
    Plugin Name:  Custom Upload Directory
    Author URI:   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/253797/111682
    */
    function custom_upload_dir_impl( $uploads ) {
        if ( defined( 'WP_UPLOAD_DIR' ) ) {
            $uploads['path'] = str_replace( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads', WP_UPLOAD_DIR, $uploads['path'] );
            $uploads['basedir'] = str_replace( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads', WP_UPLOAD_DIR, $uploads['basedir'] );
        }
        return $uploads;
    }
    add_filter( 'upload_dir',     'custom_upload_dir_impl', 1 );
```

3. In your `wp-config.php` file define the `WP_UPLOAD_DIR` constant used by the plugin.
4. In Wordpress Admin, enable the plug-in

Comment: link only answers are not much of an answer, and in any case there is an additional server configuration component required here

Comment: "Not much of an answer" solves the OPs issue and is the only answer that's been posted for 7 months.

Comment: eternal link expire.plugin stop being maintained etc, which is why they are not a good answers.

Comment: ... and as predicted it is no longer available :(

Comment: @MarkKaplun you were prescient.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to have a "cdn" type url, the easiest solution that do not require any programing is to make `HostPath/project.dev/cdn` a symlink to project.dev/wp-content/uploads. This way for theOS both paths are essentially the same. This should be easy to do if you are in full control of the server and/or have SSH access, or might require help from your hosting if you do not have this kind on access.

Another option if you have control on the web server configuration is to map the "document root" of the cdn.project.dev to the `dev/wp-content/uploads` directory.

Putting the uploaded files outside of the wordpress directory tree,as the question literally asks, is not a great idea as it is likely to break all kinds of external tools like backup utilities.